# Simplify and Sign working only in small expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to find the sign of some very long expressions, but I don't seem to make it work using Simplify[Sign[...], Assumptions ...]. Here is an example of my problem. I can easily find the sign of these two expressions:

```
exp1 = θA1^2 θAU (16 θB1^3 (1 - λ)^4 + 
 64 θB1^2 θBU (1 - λ)^3 (1 + λ) + 
 5 θBU^3 (1 - λ) (1 + λ)^3 + 
 54 θB1 θBU^2 (1 - λ^2)^2);
 Simplify[Sign[8 (exp1)] , 
   Assumptions -> {(1 - λ) > 0, θA1 > 0, θAU > 0, θB1 > 0, θBU > 0, λ > 0}]
```

This expression correctly calculates as 1. A second expression:

```
exp2 = θA1 θAU^2 (16 θB1^3 (1 - λ)^3 (1 + λ) +  44 θB1 θBU^2 (1 - λ) (1 + λ)^3 + 
 5 θBU^3 (1 + λ)^4 +  54 θB1^2 θBU (1 - λ^2)^2);
Simplify[Sign[8 (exp2)] ,  
  Assumptions -> {(1 - λ) > 0, θA1 > 0, θAU >     0, θB1 > 0, θBU > 0, λ > 0}]
```

Correctly calculates as 1 too. BUT when I try:

```
Simplify[Sign[8 (exp1 + exp2)] ,  
  Assumptions -> {(1 - λ) > 0, θA1 > 0, θAU >    0, θB1 > 0, θBU > 0, λ > 0}]
```

Then Mathematica cannot compute... Any ideas on what may be going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the value of the suboption `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` to a value higher than its default value (`4`):

```
SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]
```

> {"SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxExponent" -> 25, 
>          "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4, 
>          "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21, "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True, 
>          "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True, 
>          "ConvertTrigsToRadicals" -> False, "FiniteSumMaxTerms" -> 30, 
>          "FunctionExpandMaxSteps" -> 15, "ListableFirst" -> True, 
>          "RestartELProver" -> False, "SimplifyMaxExponents" -> 100, 
>          "SimplifyToPiecewise" -> True}}

Set the value of the suboption `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` to a higher value (say, 10):

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 10}];
Simplify[Sign[8 (exp1 + exp2)], 
   Assumptions -> {(1 - λ) > 0, θA1 > 0, θAU > 0, θB1 > 0, θBU > 0, λ > 0}]
```

> 1

Reset the suboption value to its default:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" ->  4}];
```